# How do we see the YouTube history page of another user?

Tags: youtube

When we visit http://youtube.com/my_history, we can see our own YouTube browsing history.

Is there a way to see the YouTube history page of another user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would be a direct privacy violation, therefore such feature mustn't be available, and isn't.

However, we can see others' favorites (unless it is [disabled](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=457b51d5507fb501&hl=en)) and  under some circumstances (such as sharing your activities on Twitter, Facebook, etc.) Liked videos.

Comment: ok so is it true to say that our history is never, and will never be viewable by anyone else other than anyone with access to our account?

Comment: Yes, this is true. And if you are still worried, you can [clear the history](http://google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?answer=57714)